# Component to call all material-ui Icon in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I want to implement a component which calls the corresponding icon from material-ui. I've made it work when manually calling it.

```
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
export const Icon = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MenuIcon/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to change the import for all icons.
I want to call this component the following way:

```
<Icon icon="MenuIcon" className="someClass" />
<Icon icon="LocationOn" className="someClass" />
<Icon icon="Notifications" className="OthersomeClass" />
```

I can't figure out how to import all icons and how to change my Icon component to work for any icon from the material-ui package.
Something like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import * as IconList from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'; //error

export const Icon = (props) => {
    const {icon, className} = props;
    return (
            <`${icon}` className={className} /> {//error}
    )
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to import all the icons using named imports or the star imports (* as).

Star imports should look like this

```js
import * as Icons from "@material-ui/icons";

<Icon icon={Icons.Menu} className="someClass" />
<Icon icon={Icons.AccessAlarmIcon} className="someClass" />
```

Named imports should look like this

```js
import { Menu, AccessAlarmIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

<Icon icon={Menu} className="someClass" />
<Icon icon={AccessAlarmIcon} className="someClass" />
```

You can also refactor your Icon component to utilize the React `children` prop, that way you can better compose each icon on the `Icon` component.

So it should look something like this

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Icon = ({ children }) => {
    return (
         <>{children}</>   
    )
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
<Icon>
  <Menu className="someClass" />
</Icon>

<Icon>
  <AccessAlarmIcon className="someClass" />
</Icon>
```

**PS:**

Your star imports were from `'@material-ui/icons/Menu'` as opposed to just `'@material-ui/icons'` and that caused an error